# "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous" when using conditions with lambdas in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a `dataframe`: `dt` 
and a `list` of column names: `nn_language`

**EDIT: added sample data**

```
dt = pd.DataFrame({"language1": ["english", "english123", "ingles", "ingles123", "14.0", "13", "french"],
                  "language2": ["englesh", "english123", "ingles", "ingles123", "14", "13", "french"]})
nn_language = dt.columns[dt.columns.str.contains("language")]
```

All the elements of `dt[nn_language]` are of `object` type.
What I would like to do, is change the initial values of the `dt[nn_language]` to `"english"` if the initial value is `like` `("english","ingles",14)` else i want to change the initial value to `"other"`

I have tried: `dt[nn_language].apply(lambda x: 'english' if x.str.contains('^engl|^ingl|14.0') else 'other')`

but i get an error `ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().',`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous) did not help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
check = ["english","ingles", '14']
dt[nn_language].apply(lambda x: np.where(x.isin(check) , 'english', 'other'))
```

Or:

```
dt[nn_language].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.where(x.isin(check) , 'english', 'other')))
```

It seems you need:

```
dt[nn_language].apply(lambda x: np.where(x.str.contains('^engl|^ingl|14.0')  , 'english', 'other'))
```

Comment: In your answer i think `14` is missing quotation marks, since all the elements are of type `object`. So I think it should be `["english","ingles",'14']`. Other than that it works, and i think you were slightly faster than @coldspeed !. Quick follow up question, do you know where this error that i had, came from ?

Comment: @quant No, I was first. If you must decide which answer to accept by timings.

Comment: I think you need `'14'` if string, or `14` if number. Or both.

Comment: Also, would the `isin` work if for instance i had a value `english123` ?

Comment: No, isin need exact match.

Comment: It seems you need `str.contains`.

Comment: why `dt[nn_language].apply(lambda x: 'english' if np.where(x.str.contains('^engl|^ingl|14.0')) else 'other')` yields and error but `dt[nn_language].apply(lambda x: np.where(x.str.contains('^engl|^ingl|14.0')  , 'english', 'other'))` works ?

Comment: Because `np.where` working with arrays. And your code working with items, scalars.